# What type of tree is this with the rainbow bark?

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what type of tree this is? It is located in South Florida. [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a species called [Eucalyptus deglupta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_deglupta) which may fit your photos. It is distinctly tropical and will grow in South Florida but is a rainforest tree and requires a lot of water to become fully mature as a large tree. Your photos show an exfoliating bark and the beginnings of buttressing which would fit but other examples of this species have much more dramatic colouring of the bark; perhaps it is a trick of the light and photo that do not reveal the true rainbow effect.